# Leibniz rule for expression containing derivative.

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have found the following algebraic manipulation in a solution to a homework problem, and I don't understand it. The claim is (assume continuous, differentiable $f$):

$$ \frac{x^2}{2} f^\prime(x) = \int_0^x f^\prime(x)(x-t)\,dt $$

I find this confusing, because it seems to me that I can write

$$\int_0^x t f^\prime(x)\,dt = \left[\frac{t^2}{2} f^\prime(x)\right]_0^x = \frac{x^2}{2} f^\prime(x),$$

since $f^\prime(x)$ does not depend on $t$, which does not agree with the expression above (where does the $-x$ part come from)? What am I missing?

Comment: You are right. The conlusion is wrong - the sign minus is missed.

Comment: No, the solution was correct. I missed the minus sign and have edited the question to add it. However, the minus sign is not the source of my confusion-- it's the extra term $f^\prime(x) x$ under the integral that I'm unclear on.

Comment: @ user3482876. Now it's OK. Before correction, equality was wrong as I wrote because minus was missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are equivalent. Let $t'=x-t$, then
$$
\int _0^xtf'(x)dt=\int _x^0(x-t')f'(x)d(x-t')=-\int _x^0(x-t')f'(x)dt'=\int_0^x(x-t')f'(x)dt'
$$

Comment: I don't see a problem with your calculation, but I find this result very strange-looking. After trying it on a few examples of $f^\prime(x)$ I am convinced it is correct, though. Do you know a geometric interpretation?